# "Public DNS" v.s. "Public IP" of AWS for running geth RPC

Tags: web3js, truffle, aws

In my AWS ec2 instance, I run geth and specify --rpcport and --rpcaddr using "Public DNS" like this:

```
geth --datadir "./signer1/data" --networkid 55661 --port 2000 --rpc --rpcport 5566 --rpcaddr "ec2-13-114-49-66.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com" --rpcapi "eth,personal,web3,net,db" --mine
```

It will work fine, but if I specify --rpcaddr as "Public IP":

```
geth --datadir "./signer1/data" --networkid 55661 --port 2000 --rpc --rpcport 5566 --rpcaddr "13.114.49.66" --rpcapi "eth,personal,web3,net,db" --mine
```

I will get **Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""** when I try to deploy the contract through web3.

What's the reason causes this different behavior?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Untested on my end. However, I think there is a reasonable chance the answer may be CORS. When your RPC client attempts to send a request, your `geth` may be replying that the response is coming from a different host (address vs. IP) than the one you are accessing your `geth` through. If this is the case, you'll need to set one of the CORS command line options.